# Cassandra : Restoring data node after deleting one of the data directories

Tags: cassandra

I've a 4 node cassandra cluster with a replication factor 3 and have a min of 150 million records. In each of them I've 3 data directories. In one of the node, I've deleted one of the data directory. So after stating cassandra we got the below error in system.log.

> org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Found system table files, but they couldn't be loaded!

So I configured new data directories in cassandra.yaml file and the cassandra was able to start successfully. I did this since I knew the data would be replicated since i've a factor of 3. But as per my finding, it is not getting replication since the disk size in node 1 is not getting increased. How to achieve this? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run `bin/nodetool repair` on the node that experienced the mishap. This will pull missing data from the remaining replications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by @ralf's answer, running

> bin/nodetool repair

solved the problem.